# Xamarin Azure pipelines: Error XA3007: Could not link native shared library: libxamarin-app.so

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build an Android apk from our Xamarin.Forms app in Azure pipelines but the job fails with the following error:

```
_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries:
  [aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\typemaps.arm64-v8a.o: No such file or directory
  [aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\environment.arm64-v8a.o: No such file or directory
  [aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\aarch64-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\compressed_assemblies.arm64-v8a.o: No such file or directory
  [i686-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\i686-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\typemaps.x86.o: No such file or directory
  [i686-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\i686-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\environment.x86.o: No such file or directory
  [i686-linux-android-ld.EXE stderr] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\ndk\i686-linux-android-ld.EXE: cannot find obj\\110\android\compressed_assemblies.x86.o: No such file or directory
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1900,3): Error XA3007: Could not link native shared library: libxamarin-app.so
```

I am using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012. The only documentation I can find is [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3520) but it does not provide a solution. Below is the yml I am using, from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

  variables:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
    
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildVersionOption: '16.0'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apksign: false
    zipalign: false
    apkFiles: '$(outputDirectory)/*.apk'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(outputDirectory)/*.apk'
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the MacOS vm, do you face the same error?

Comment: Yes I did, then I get the following error: The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized.

Comment: I can fix the above error but then I get a new error, which I don't know how to fix: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: The attribute "CopyToOutputDirectory" in element <None> is unrecognized.

Comment: So I just copy pasted the yaml directly from MS docs and suddenly the build works fine. Only differences: Apparently I used an extra leading space on each line, hmmm...

Comment: @Niels I had a classic pipeline which built fine. I copied and pasted the YAML from the classic pipeline, now I get this error. No leading spaces that I can see. VS2019 windows build server. Any thoughts?